# Word or phrase similar to Unique Selling Proposition (USP) referring to the seller (manufacturer)

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, marketing

A unique selling proposition (USP) attempts to answer the customer's question of “Why should I buy your product instead of someone else’s?”

Is there a similar word or phrase which is a counter part to USP but referring pitching a product to internal clients attempting to answer the question "Why should we make this product" over other product ideas. A word / phrase that will be used to refer to the advantages the manufacturer (seller) has in making this product.

I am not looking for a specific marketing term a generic one is also fine. Also need not be single word.

Comment: In ***British*** English, USP is [as likely to stand for *Unique Selling **Point*** as ***Proposition***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Unique+Selling+Proposition%2CUnique+Selling+Point&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) But regardless of that the answer to "Why should we make this product?" should normally be some variant of ***Because people will want to buy it at a price much higher than our production costs***. In which context, it's perfectly okay to say *Because it has a **USP** [for which they will pay more]*, regardless of exactly what it stands for.

Comment: In the US, "USP" stands for "United States Pharmacopeia".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get your point - in the end everyone will want to look at the one product that makes the most money however in getting there there could be other factors we need to look at, like going with a product that is most likely to be successful but not make the most profit or a product that that may be least risky if it fails.

Comment: There's also the matter of "leveraging" any *specific* resources one company might have (of various types, including personnel, location, existing plant, etc.). As with people, companies should ***play to their strengths***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think I'll go with "leveraging" it feels right. If you post as answer I will accept. Thanks..

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know I'm old but I really hate the verb "to leverage". Sets my teeth on edge every time I hear it!

Comment: @BoldBen: I know what you mean. Checking the full OED it seems that the noun ***leverage*** was first "verbified" before WW2, but originally that was only for the literal "mechanical" physics sense. It seems we have Adam Smith's *Supermoney* (**1972**) to thank for the economics business jargon sense that gets up your (our?! :) nose!

Comment: @FumbleFingers My biggest problem with it is that "leverage" in stock exchange terms relates to the debt load on a company. A "highly leveraged company" is one where the debt load is a very large percentage of the stock valuation. The buzzword meaning of "to leverage" seems to have become "make your existing assets more productive of profit". I really don't see how the second usage relates to the first unless the speaker works for a slightly dodgy finance house. Oh, just a minute...

Comment: @BoldBen: ***Give me a lever and I will move the world** [even with my puny human muscles].* Or ***Let me leverage our puny corporate assets into a fortune** [using the "lever" of interest rates].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers But why did they need a new verb when "to lever" already existed. Unless it was to bamboozle and obfuscate. Oh, sorry, I think I know now

Comment: @BoldBen: I see *The Proactive Executive* and similar published material occasionally advise their would-be business-magnate readership: [*You should should **leverage** your strengths.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22should+leverage+your+strengths%22) But I'm sticking with ***play to***, as per earlier comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I once saw Jeremy Paxman interviewing some West Coast smarta**e who came out with a string of Newspeak including "leverage" as a verb. If looks could kill he would have been dead in his chair. By the way I always pronounce the verb as "levverage" leaving "leeverage" for the noun. I don't want to assiciate myself with it any more than I can help. I don't want to sound like one of Shakespeare's Two Pedants but there are limits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on the request for a word / phrase...

*used to refer to **the advantages the manufacturer (seller) has** in making this product.*

...I'd say the company should ***play to their strengths***.

---

> **play to (one's) strengths**

1. To prioritize using one's natural abilities and specific skills, especially by pursuing tasks or goals suited to such skills.
   *After his disappointing Western-themed family drama, it's nice to see the director once again playing to her strengths with a film grounded in humor and wit.*
2. To put one in a position that allows them to best use their natural abilities and specific skills.
   *We're going to have everyone try out the different positions on the field so we can find everyone a role that plays to their strengths.*

Essentially that means the company should choose to make a product they're particularly good at making (specifically, something they're *much better than their competitors* at making).

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the phrases “standout production” and *standout manufacture” in this context.